# Running from usb installation of Windows Developer Preview (8)

Tags: usb, installation, windows-8-preview

i decided to install windows 8 on my PC without using DVD - i used a windows 7 usb/dvd download tool to extract windows developer preview on my usb, all works fine but after boot my USB screen is black at 30-60 seconds end computer reboots.

anyone have a answer for this problem (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

You should let it run for as long as you can. It's a Dev preview and isn't optimized for speed.

Depending on your hardware, Windows does a number of task after you reboot from setup. I'd let it run.

For example, my laptop run for about 10 minutes and rebooted twice after the initial install.